# Custom Picker Rendered With Search Bar(or Entry)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I want to create a custom picker that has search capability in its items. To do that I want to add search bar or entry to the picker. I read and watch many tutorials about custom renderers but, most of them(except one) are about changing appearance not adding new capability to it. So, I want to ask some questions about this;

- Is this kind of thing is feasible? (Picker with search bar)
- Am I need to create completely new ViewRenderer or inheriting from
- PickerRenderer is ok?
- If I'm going to create new ViewRenderer where to start?
- If inheriting from Picker Renderer is ok, then how to add new
  controls to the renderers?

Comment: Can I see what are you trying to achieve here because your question is quite confusing for me!

Comment: Have you considered third party controls like Syncfusion or Telerik, I believe they have stuff like this.

Comment: Not  - @BenReierson